# Bank Account Java Program

Tags: java, arrays, loops, menu

I am creating a bank account program for my java class that is suppose to manage up to 5 different bank accounts.  The program has to allow the creation of a new account, which I have done, allow deposit and withdraw, which is also done, the 2 parts I cannot get to work are 1: the bank can only have up to 5 accounts, so if a 6th is trying to be created, a message comes up saying that 5 are already created, and 2: one of the options has to print out all the account balances of current accounts in the bank.

This is my code as of now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bankapp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Bank myBank = new Bank();

    int user_choice = 2;


    do {
        //display menu to user
        //ask user for his choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Open a new bank account");
        System.out.println("2) Deposit to a bank account");
        System.out.println("3) Withdraw to bank account");
        System.out.println("4) Print account balance");
        System.out.println("5) Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter choice [1-5]: ");
        user_choice = s.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Enter a customer name");
                    String cn = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter a opening balance");
                    double d = s.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Account was created and it has the following number: " + myBank.openNewAccount(cn, d));
                    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int an = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter a deposit amount");
                    double da = s.nextDouble();
                    myBank.depositTo(an, da);
                    break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int acn = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter a withdraw amount");
                    double wa = s.nextDouble();
                    myBank.withdrawFrom(acn, wa);
                    break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int anum = s.nextInt();
                    myBank.printAccountInfo(anum);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    System.out.println("Here are the balances " + "for each account:");
            case 6:
                System.exit(0);
        }
}
while (user_choice != '6');
}

static class Bank {
private BankAccount[] accounts;     // all the bank accounts at this bank
private int numOfAccounts = 5;      // the number of bank accounts at this bank

// Constructor: A new Bank object initially doesn’t contain any accounts.
public Bank() {
    accounts = new BankAccount[5];
    numOfAccounts = 0;
    }

// Creates a new bank account using the customer name and the opening balance given as parameters
// and returns the account number of this new account. It also adds this account into the account list
// of the Bank calling object.
public int openNewAccount(String customerName, double openingBalance) {

    BankAccount b = new BankAccount(customerName, openingBalance);
    accounts[numOfAccounts] = b;
    numOfAccounts++;
    return b.getAccountNum();
}

// Withdraws the given amount from the account whose account number is given. If the account is
// not available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void withdrawFrom(int accountNum, double amount) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
            accounts[i].withdraw(amount);
            System.out.println("Amount withdrawn successfully");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
    }

// Deposits the given amount to the account whose account number is given. If the account is not
// available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void depositTo(int accountNum, double amount) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
            accounts[i].deposit(amount);
            System.out.println("Amount deposited successfully");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}

// Prints the account number, the customer name and the balance of the bank account whose
// account number is given. If the account is not available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void printAccountInfo(int accountNum) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                    System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                    return;
                }
            }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}


public void printAccountInfo(int accountNum, int n) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                            System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                            return;
                        }
                    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
    }

}





  static class BankAccount{

       private int accountNum;
       private String customerName;
       private double balance;
       private  static int noOfAccounts=0;

       public String getAccountInfo(){
           return "Account number: " + accountNum + "\nCustomer Name: " + customerName + "\nBalance:" + balance +"\n";
       }


       public BankAccount(String abc, double xyz){
         customerName = abc;
         balance = xyz;
         noOfAccounts ++;
         accountNum = noOfAccounts;
       }

    public int getAccountNum(){
        return accountNum;
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){

        if (amount<=0) {
            System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
        } else {
            balance = balance + amount;

        }
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (amount<=0){
             System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
         }
        else
        {
            if (balance < amount) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
            } else {
                balance = balance - amount;

            }
        }
    }

}//end of class
```

The program runs fine, I just need to add these two options, and cannot get them to work properly, how would I go about doing this? Also, options 3 and 4 should not work if no accounts have been created yet.  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: this is what I tried, I keep getting a this method must return type int error.

```
public int openNewAccount(String customerName, double openingBalance) {
    if(numOfAccounts > 5)
    {
        System.out.println("5 accounts already exist");
    }
    else
    {
    BankAccount b = new BankAccount(customerName, openingBalance);
    accounts[numOfAccounts] = b;
    numOfAccounts++;
    return b.getAccountNum();
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: I added a return statement, now when it runs it will open accounts up to number 5, but for every account after number 5 it just says the account number is 5 again instead of not opening an account.

```
public int openNewAccount(String customerName, double openingBalance) {
    if(numOfAccounts > 5)
    {
        System.out.println("5 accounts already exist");
    }
    else
    {
    BankAccount b = new BankAccount(customerName, openingBalance);
    accounts[numOfAccounts] = b;
    numOfAccounts++;
    return b.getAccountNum();
    }
    return numOfAccounts;
}
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with adding the remaining two options? StackOverflow isn't going to do your homework for you :) Is this a code design question, or a recommendation on technique? How do you think you should go about it, from what you know so far? To me, it seems that it will somehow involve triggering an error when you try to open a new account and you're over the limit, for example. Look into exceptions or consider returning something indicating an error state.

Comment: I don't expect you to, I have for the first part I have tried doing something along the lines of if(numOfAccounts > 5) then no account created, but I keep getting errors, and for part 2, I'm just not sure on how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I see. Edit your post and put "Edit:" or "Update:" in bold, and below that, show what you tried and what errors you're getting. Also look at the related questions on the right--others have come here for help with the same assignment ;)

Comment: openNewAccount returns an Int required so  if you cant create a bank account it still has to return something of the int form; I'm not sure why it even needs to return an int here; this function should be a void; returning b.getAccountNUm() is useless..

Comment: Java has collections, which allow you to create any number of objects. If you use ArrayList you can create as many accounts as your JVM has memory (or the limit of your datatype) - both in billions!

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple.  Create a list of size 5 and add the account into that list when user is created one.  Before adding just make a check whether list size <= 5. If it is true, go ahead and add the account, otherwise throw an error

For option 2, just iterate through the list and display the results

Answer (score 1):

1; in the openNewBank account method; before creating the new Bank account and increasing the count by 1; check if the number of account is already at 5 or higher and if it is dont create the account and dont increase the count.

2: Loop through the number of account variable and print.

Comment: what would the code for that look like, I tried a few different ways an none seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

I added password system to it. and nice looking account num. 
Code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class Computer_Bank_of_India {
public static int NewRandom(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
    Bank myBank = new Bank();
    int Option = 1, Account_Number, Account_Password, atempts = 0, Pass;
    String Name;
    double Balance, Money;
    System.out.println("Please wait, the system is starting...");
    while(Option !=5) {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println("1) Open a new bank account");
        Thread.sleep(250);
        System.out.println("2) Deposit to a bank account");
        Thread.sleep(250);
        System.out.println("3) Withdraw to bank account");
        Thread.sleep(250);
        System.out.println("4) Print the detailed account information including last transactions");
        Thread.sleep(250);
        System.out.println("5) Quit");       
        System.out.println();      
        System.out.print("                       Enter Option [1-5]: ");
        Option = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        switch(Option) {
            case 1 : System.out.println("Enter a customer name :");
                     Name = br.readLine();
                     System.out.println("Enter a opening balance :");
                     Balance = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                     Thread.sleep(250);
                     System.out.println("Creating your account....");
                     Thread.sleep(500);
                     int[] arrDetails= myBank.AddNewAccount(Name, Balance);                     
                     System.out.println("Account Has been created\n Account number: " + arrDetails[0]+"\nYour password : "+ arrDetails[1]);
                     break;
            case 2 : System.out.println("Enter a account number :");
                     Account_Number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     System.out.println("Enter a account password :");
                     Account_Password = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     System.out.println("Enter a deposit amount :");
                     Money = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                     myBank.Deposit(Account_Number, Account_Password, Money);
                     break;
            case 3 : System.out.println("Enter a account number :");
                     Account_Number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     System.out.println("Enter a account password :");
                     Account_Password = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     System.out.println("Enter a deposit amount :");
                     Money = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                     myBank.Withdraw(Account_Number, Account_Password, Money);
                     break;
            case 4 : System.out.println("Enter a account number :");
                     Account_Number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     System.out.println("Enter a account password :");
                     Account_Password = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     myBank.Transactions(Account_Number, Account_Password);
                     break;
            case 5 : System.out.println("Please Enter your password :");
                     Pass = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                     if(Pass == myBank.Password) {
                         System.out.println("                       System shutting down.....");
                         Option = 5;
                         break;
                     } 
                     else {
                         Thread.sleep(250);
                         System.out.println("You have enter a wrong password. Please try again");
                         Option = 0;
                     }
            default: System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
        }
    }
}
static class Bank {
    private int Password=2684;
    private BankAccount[] accounts;
    private int numOfAccounts;
    public Bank() {
        accounts = new BankAccount[100];
        numOfAccounts = 0;
    }
    public int [] AddNewAccount(String Name, Double Balance) {
        BankAccount b = new BankAccount(Name, Balance);
        accounts[numOfAccounts] = b;
        numOfAccounts++;
        int Acc = b.getAccountNum()[0];
        int Pass = b.getAccountNum()[1];
        int[]details = {Acc, Pass};
        return details;
    }
    public void Withdraw(int Account_Number, int pass, double Money) {
        for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {     
            int a = accounts[i].getAccountNum()[0];
            if (Account_Number == a) {
                int p = accounts[i].getAccountNum()[1];
                if( pass == p) {
                    accounts[i].withdraw(Money);
                    return;
                }
            }   
        }  
        System.out.println("                       You have entered a wrong Account number or Password.");
    }
    public void Deposit(int Account_Number, int pass, double Money) {  
        for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {     
            int a = accounts[i].getAccountNum()[0];
            if (Account_Number == a) {
                int p = accounts[i].getAccountNum()[1];
                if( pass == p) {
                    accounts[i].deposit(Money);
                    return;   
                }
            }   
        }  
        System.out.println("                       You have entered a wrong Account number or Password.");
    }
    public void Transactions(int Account_Number, int pass) {
        for(int i = 0;i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
            int a = accounts[i].getAccountNum()[0];
            if (Account_Number ==  a ) {
                int p = accounts[i].getAccountNum()[1];
                if( pass == p) {
                    System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                    System.out.println("                        Last transaction: " + accounts[i].getTransactionInfo(accounts[i].getNumberOfTransactions()-1));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("                       You have entered a wrong Account number or Password.");
    }
}
static class BankAccount{
    private int User_Password;
    private int accountNum;
    private String customerName;
    private double balance;
    private double[] transactions;
    private String[] transactionsSummary;
    private int numOfTransactions;
    private  static int noOfAccounts=0;
    public String getAccountInfo(){          
        return "                        Account number: " + accountNum + "\n                        Customer Name: " + customerName + "\n                        Balance:" + balance +"\n";
    }
    public String getTransactionInfo(int n) {
        String transaction = transactionsSummary[n];
        return transaction;
        }
    public BankAccount(String abc, double xyz){        
        customerName = abc;        
        balance = xyz;        
        noOfAccounts ++;
        User_Password = NewRandom(1000, 9999);
        accountNum = NewRandom(800000000, 999999999);       
        transactions = new double[100];                         
        transactionsSummary = new String[100];               
        transactions[0] = balance;                      
        transactionsSummary[0] = "A balance of : Rs" + Double.toString(balance) + " was deposited.";       
        numOfTransactions = 1;             
    }
    public int [] getAccountNum(){
        int account = accountNum;
        int Pass = User_Password;
        int [] details = {account, Pass};
        return details;
    }
    public int getNumberOfTransactions() {           
        return numOfTransactions;          
    }         
    public void deposit(double amount){         
        if (amount<=0) {         
            System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");        
        } else {          
            balance = balance + amount;            
            transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;            
            transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "Rs." + Double.toString(amount) + " was deposited.";            
            numOfTransactions++;
            System.out.println("                       Amount deposited successfully");
        }         
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount) {                   
        if (amount<=0){                
            System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive"); 
        } 
        else {  
            if (balance < amount) {  
                System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
            } else {  
                balance = balance - amount;
                transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
                transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "Rs." + Double.toString(amount) + " was withdrawn.";
                numOfTransactions++;
                System.out.println("                       Amount Withdrawn successfully");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```